# .NET Math.Round(<double>,<int>,MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) not working correctly

Tags: c#

I am using Visual Studio Professional 2012.
I created a new C# ConsoleApplication, targeting .NET Framework 4.5, with following code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double x = 2.44445;
        double y = Math.Round(x, 4, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
        Console.WriteLine(y);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

The expected result should be 2.4445, but it actually returns 2.4444.
//Same result with previous framework version, and I tried VCE2010.

I know such problem usually results from the way double data type is stored (i.e. finite decimals converted to infinite binary fraction). But I didn't expect this to happen with only 5 decimal digits like 2.44445

I'm worrying if such thing could happen with even shorter decimals. I would also like to learn a safer way to round (using away from zero convention) in C#.
Thanks.

Comment: `Math.Round(new Decimal(2.44445), 4, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)` does give 2.4445. So using `Decimal` would an option to consider.

Comment: I can confirm that it does happen with even shorter decimals.

Answer (score 11):

This is indeed due to the fragile precision of floating-point numbers.  0.5 can be stored perfectly in IEEE floating point, but 0.45, 0.445 etc. cannot.  For example, the actual value that is stored when you specify 2.44445 is 11009049289107177/4503599627370496 which is 2.44449999999999989519494647... It should now be obvious why the number is rounded the way it is.

If you need to store fractional numbers precisely, consider using the `decimal` type instead.

Comment: Thanks. I just checked how decimal type is stored and am convinced it won't incur the problem as with floating binary.

Answer (score 4):

[Notes from msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f5898377.aspx):

> Because of the loss of precision that can result from representing
>   decimal values as floating-point numbers or performing arithmetic
>   operations on floating-point values, in some cases the Round(Double,
>   Int32, MidpointRounding) method may not appear to round midpoint
>   values as specified by the mode parameter. This is illustrated in the
>   following example, where 2.135 is rounded to 2.13 instead of 2.14.
>   This occurs because internally the method multiplies value by
>   10digits, and the **multiplication operation in this case suffers from a
>   loss of precision**.

This is how Round implemented:

```
double num = roundPower10Double[digits];
value *= num;
if (mode == MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
{
    double num2 = SplitFractionDouble(&value);
    if (Abs(num2) >= 0.5)
    {
        value += Sign(num2);
    }
}
```

As you can see, value is multiplied by num, which is a value from

```
roundPower10Double = new double[] { 1.0, 10.0, 100.0, 1000.0, 10000.0, 
      100000.0, 1000000.0, 10000000.0, 100000000.0, 1000000000.0, 10000000000,  
      100000000000, 1000000000000, 10000000000000, 100000000000000, 1E+15 };
```

So, actually you have `2.44445 * 10000.0 - 24444,0` which gives `0,499999999996362`. Which is less than `0.5`. Thus you have `2.4444`.

Comment: It also amazed me that .NET does 3.44445 right, when 2.44445D and 3.44445D has only 1 bit difference. Seems dangerous to play with multiplication on double :)

Comment: @limilaw It's not .NET that's getting it right/wrong. It's IEEE. [This Web page](http://babbage.cs.qc.cuny.edu/IEEE-754/) lets you see the internal representation of IEEE floating point values. And it's not actually right/wrong; you are erroneously expecting exact decimal precision from a binary floating point format. (Imagine an alien with three fingers who says, "Stupid decimal humans. I ask them for 1/3 and they come back with this inexact value. 0.3333333")